# How do I trap the queen once it pins my rook?

Tags: analysis, strategy, tactics, middlegame, queens

I am playing as Black in this game, and after 10. Qg4, I realize that White wanted my rook.  I knew I could trap the queen once it went for the rook (11. Qxg7), but I forgot how. I went on to win the game but I would still like a refresher.

```
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2013.04.17"]
[White "ilikefood7"]
[Black "MDMoore313"]
[Result "0-1"]
[WhiteElo "1300"]
[BlackElo "1298"]
[TimeControl "10|0"]
[Termination "MDMoore313 won by checkmate"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Nc3 b6 4. Bb5 Bb7 5. d3 e5 6. Bxc6 Bxc6 7. Nxe5 Qc7 8. Bf4 Bd6 9. Nxc6 Qxc6 10. Qg4 Bxf4 11. Qxg7 O-O-O 12. Qxh8 Qg6 13. Nd5 Re8 14. Nxf4 Qh6 15. Nd5 f5 16. O-O Rf8 17. Qe5 d6 18. Qc3 f4 19. d4 f3 20. dxc5 bxc5 21. g3 Qh3 22. Ne3 Nf6 23. Kh1 Ng4 24. Nxg4 Qg2#
```

Comment: Simpler than trying to trap the queen is just 11...Qf6, protecting the rook and remaining a piece up.

Comment: @dfan how would I be a piece up?

Comment: @MDMoore313 - Because you have 5 minor pieces to your opponents 4, so by playing 11...Qf6, if 12. QxQ, then you just recapture with your Knight and you remain a piece up.

Comment: @xaisoft  I see now, I read the comment too fast and was thinking 10...f6 for some reason.

Comment: Technically, you have 2 minor pieces to your opponent's 1. (Queens and rooks are major pieces).

Comment: dfan is correct, I always refer to everything as a minor piece. Gotta change that habit.

Comment: That's not a pin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can trap the Queen, but you ought to be able to force the Queens off the board.  Once you do that your extra piece becomes very powerful.  After `11... Qf6` white can only avoid a queen trade by `12. Qg4` but is followed by `12... h5` and preparing for an eventual Rg8.  Black's having a great game though his King is in a drafty place.  Razor sharp.

Comment: After 12...Qf6 Black is down the exchange, not up a piece. Perhaps you meant 11...Qf6?

Comment: +1 for being first to point out 11...Qf6, *and* for complimenting my game :-)

Answer (score 5):

*Overall*

An interesting match. `21. g3` was certainly a gift from your opponent.

---

*Trapping the queen*

As for trapping the queen, in this position, you cannot. Any efforts to actually trade the queen will end up either failing or losing material (such as losing both rooks to the queen after some material exchange).

```
[FEN ""]

1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Nc3 b6 4.Bb5 Bb7 5.d3 e5 6.Bxc6 Bxc6 7.Nxe5 Qc7 8.Bf4 Bd6 9.Nxc6 Qxc6 10.Qg4 Bxf4 11.Qxg7 Qg6 12.Qxh8 f6 13.Nd5
```

---

*Taking the lead*

A better approach would be to instantly punish your opponent for being greedy with `11. .. Qf6

```
[FEN ""]

1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Nc3 b6 4.Bb5 Bb7 5.d3 e5 6.Bxc6 Bxc6 7.Nxe5 Qc7 8.Bf4 Bd6 9.Nxc6 Qxc6 10.Qg4 Bxf4 11.Qxg7 Qf6
```

Had White taken on `f4` instead of on `g7` they would have enjoyed a `+1.77` advantage. However, after Black playing `11.Qf6` Black now enjoys a `1.33` advantage (which turns into a `2.14` advantage should White shy away from trading queens).

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like after 11. Qxg7 Qg6 12. Qxh8 d6, black threatens Be5 picking up the queen.  Then if d4, White can play for 0-0-0 and Bh6, which might be the direction you were thinking.